# Question about normalized cross correlation

Tags: numpy, normalization, cross-correlation

I am trying to understand cross correlation for pattern matching, so i developed a simple script to help me understand what is happening. 
I do understand the process and match of cross correlation, however things are a bit fuzzy for normalized cross correlation and why it seems to work better on the problem I am working on, however I do understand its math.
Problem Statement:
for a array `I` of length `n` with random elements, I extract a block of `m`elements from `I` starting at a random position `k` I want to find the position `k` using cross correlation. This is the 1D equivalent of doing pattern matching for an image, but in 1D. Again, this is just an exercise. Below is the complete code I am using to implement the above:

```
pattern_len = 4
img_len = 11

img = numpy.random.rand((img_len))*numpy.random.rand(1)*10
it = numpy.random.randint(0, (img_len-pattern_len))

pattern = img[it:it+pattern_len]

match = numpy.zeros(img_len)

for i in range(0, img_len):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0
    for j in range(0, pattern_len):
        v = 0
        if (not (i+j > (img_len - 1))):
            v = img[i+j]
        a += v*pattern[j]
        b += v*v
        c += pattern[j]*pattern[j]

    #match[i] = a
    match[i] = a/numpy.sqrt(b*c)

id = numpy.argmax(match)

if (id == it):
    print("correct index found, it: {0}, index: {1}".format(it, id))
else:
    print("INcorrect index found, it: {0}, index: {1}".format(it, id))
```

My question is: if i use `match[i] = a` (cross correlation) instead of `match[i] = a/numpy.sqrt(a*b)` (normalized cross correlation) I get the incorrect output most of the time, but if I use the normalized version, the output is correct every single time. 
Like I said I do understand the math or doing the normalized cross correlation, however I do not understand in a fundamental level, why it works when the non-normalized version does not. 
I also tried to normalize both inputs to range from -1 to 1, and use the non-normalized version, but it still did not work. Why?

Thanks for the help